# After singing, how long do you remain warmed up for?

Tags: voice, warm-up

If you are singing on and off during the day, and begin with a decent warm up in the morning, how frequently do you need to sing/do exercises to remain warmed up? Doing a warm-up over and over again during the day would be a little irritating but maybe it's what's required?

Or looking another way, how might you remain 'warm' all day, what is the minimum you need to do to achieve this?

Comment: I get tired out after an hour or so (on a good day, if I'm being honest with myself), and at that point being tired cancels out being warm - at least for me. On guitar, my peak performance for a day is literally a peak - a moment in time. Before the peak, I'm warming up. After the peak, I'm getting more tired. For a gig I try to enter the good zone before the gig starts with a proper warm up, then one song is magically awesome, and then I hope the end of the gig comes before getting tired takes me out of the good zone again. "Warming up" again would just make me more tired.

Answer (score 1):

The primary purpose of warming up is indicated by the term **"warm" up**.  Whether warming up for sports activity or singing - it literally means raising the core temperature of the muscles you plan to use in order to increase the efficiency of the muscles and reduce the likelihood of injury.

As it relates to singing, a warm up routine will also serve to loosen up (like stretching) your vocal folds.  Asking tight vocal folds to respond to sudden high intensity singing is a recipe for injury.

Muscles are warmed by increasing the blood flow by increasing the movement of the muscle.  As the neurons fire to tell the muscles to contract, heat is produced in the muscle tissue.  Once the exercise (such as singing) has ceased, the muscles begin to cool.  After 30 minutes of inactivity, a new warm up would be indicated.

Excessive talking after warming up the muscles involved in singing, might delay the time needed for those muscles to completely cool down.  So the amount of time elapsed before a new warm up is indicated may vary to some extent depending on how much talking you do between singing sets.

But it is probably a good idea to do some warm up prior to singing again if more than 30 minutes has gone by since you last sang - just to be on the safe side.

Comment: A tip -- don't drink ice water or cold water or cold beer while singing or before singing. Drink water or any other drink at room temperature or hotter. Drinking something cold causes constriction in your throat and interferes with singing freely. Also avoid milk, ice cream, yogurt. Some people find that too much tannic acid or caffeine (tea and coffee) dry out the throat. You can have fatigue if you sing when your throat is dry. All of these things may reverse the effects of warming up your voice.

Comment: @WheatWilliams  All excellent advice Wheat.  When I am performing I drink room temperature water.  At the end of the night before packing up my gear - I will have a cold beer.